# Compare two time series

Tags: time-series, entropy, mutual-information, cross-correlation, granger-causality

I have two time series that come from the same system. One is taken from the whole system, and the other is taken from, say, 10% of the system. The two time series have the same frequency. Is there a measure to know how similar these two time series are?

Answer (score 3):

Permutation Distribution Clustering is a clustering method for time series. Dissimilarity of time series is formalized as the divergence between their permutation distributions. The permutation distribution was proposed as measure of the complexity of a time series.

PDC is available as an R package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdc/index.html

Answer (score -1):

To begin with I would create a third series (the remaining 90%) and compare it to the 10% series in ways I have discussed before.